# Group multiple objects

Tags: java, graph, nearest-neighbor

I am making a game where there are lots of rooms and these rooms are connected by passage ways. The whole thing is generated randomly by creating rooms of random size across the area, and then, it finds the nearest room that it is not already connected to by a passageway and creates a passageway between them.

```
private void LinkRooms() {
    for(Room r : new ArrayList<Room>(rooms)){
        if(r != null) {
            Room r2 = getNearestNeighbour(r);
            if(r2 != null) createPassage(r, r2);
        }
    }
}
```

Find the nearest neighbour:

```
private Room getNearestNeighbour(Room r) {
    double dist = 10000000;
    Room room = null;
    for(Room r2 : new ArrayList<Room>(rooms)){
        if(!r.linked.contains(r2) && r2 != r){
            int cx = r.x + r.size_x/2;
            int cy = r.y + r.size_y/2;
            int cx2 = r2.x + r2.size_x/2;
            int cy2 = r2.y + r2.size_y/2;
            double distance = Math.sqrt((cx - cx2) * (cx - cx2) + (cy - cy2) * (cy - cy2));
            if(distance <= dist){ 
                dist = distance; 
                room = r2;
            }
        }
    }
    return room;
}
```

Create the passageway between the two rooms:

```
private void createPassage(Room r, Room r2) {
    int centrex = roundm(r.x + r.size_x/2 - Tile.size/2);
    int centrey = roundm(r.y + r.size_y/2 - Tile.size/2);
    int centrex2 = roundm(r2.x + r2.size_x/2 - Tile.size/2);
    int centrey2 = roundm(r2.y + r2.size_y/2 - Tile.size/2);

    r.linked.add(r2);//here is where the room adds the rooms that it is directly linked to
    r2.linked.add(r);

/**I tried to approach my problem by giving rooms a unique id, 
which is equal to their position in the array, and then I thought 
it would spread this id to each of the other rooms, however, because 
of the order that they find the nearest neighbour being "random" some
would end with different id's. Note that I use the colour so that I 
can see it visually.**/

    if(r.id < r2.id){
        r2.id = r.id;
        r2.colour = r.colour;
    }else{
        r.id = r2.id;
        r.colour = r2.colour;
    }
    for(int xtile = 0; xtile < Math.abs(centrex2-centrex); xtile+=Tile.size){
        if(centrex < centrex2){
            ... // create new tile with owner "r"
        }else{
            ...
        }
    }
    for(int ytile = 0; ytile < Math.abs(centrey2-centrey); ytile+=Tile.size){
        ...
    }
}
```

This does not connect all of the rooms in the area usually. The rooms tend to form groups, but the graph is not a connected graph. Each room stores the rooms it is directly connected to in an ArrayList, but I need to group together all of the rooms that have a path to each other and assign them a group id. So, how do I organise these rooms into groups of each individual connected graph?